# How can I put a computer to sleep without login

Tags: windows, sleep

How do I put the WINDOWS computer to sleep from the CTRL/ALT/DEL command log-in screen without having to enter my password and log-in?  All the computers in our network must be password protected, and sometimes I'm ready to leave, am required to leave my computer asleep if I want remote access from home (and I do) and I can't find anywhere to put it back to sleep without logging in first.

Comment: Are the power options set to have the computer go to sleep after a given time? If so, there would be no reason to log back in. It will go to sleep after the given time has elapsed.

Answer (score 1):

After doing a Ctrl + Alt + Del - you will find the Power Options in the 
bottom right corner (under Windows 7). 
From there you can hybernate